# How to rewrite the route name Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have url something like http://local.magentodemo.com/customer/index/index
is there any way to rename the route so it must look like http://local.magentodemo.com/customer/index.php

any suggestions, help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you want rewrite the url dynamically ?? or only one url that you want to rewrite..??

Comment: i want to rewrite only one URL with .php extention

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel then :

```
Marketing > URL Rewrites > Add URL Rewrite >
```

Request Path :

http://local.magentodemo.com/customer/index.php

Target Path :

http://local.magentodemo.com/customer/index/index

add the above link in the field as given.